# Rails 5 nested form with modal bootstrap and Cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm trying to create a bootstrap modal nested form with cocoon gem. My project follows the simple example on main page (https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). I have a main model Project that has many Tasks

I'm trying to create a new recored Task with bootstrap modal inside Project.

I tried make it in so many different ways that a I can't tell whats going wrong or types of error I had.

Anyone could provide an example of a modal with a Cocoon form for a model Taks?

Comment: Hey, can you make your question a bit more precise? It is not 100% clear what you want the modal to do

Comment: Do you want a nested form inside a modal? Do you want to add nested items inside a modal? What is the intention of the modal? What should it do? Can you show us what you tried (view-code) and how it behaves (or what error it gives) and how you expect it to behave?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your intention is that the modal asks for a confirmation by the user.

Dig a little deeper into the readme of the gem because what you want do might require you do craft a significant amount of frontend developing.

`cocoon` fires specific events when the *link to add association* button is clicked (before and after insert/remove). You should hook into the `cocoon:before-insert` event.

The guide provides a simplified example for this in the section *Canceling a callback*

See https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#canceling-a-callback

Comment: "I assume that your intention is that the modal asks for a confirmation by the user."
Not really.
I do not know how to create a modal and associate it with the parent model, that's my real problem.

Comment: Again, what do you want the modal to do? When should it appear?